# Multi threaded Producer Consumer with bounded buffer

Tags: java, multithreading

I've developed the following multi-threaded code and would like a review. It is supposed to be implementing the Producer-consumer problem as defined [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem).

I have multiple consumers and one producer. I would like to know whether there are any problems with my use of concurrency and also if you have any suggestions on how to better implement the solution. I don't have a lot of experience with concurrent programming and am trying to improve.

```
package consumerproducer;

import java.util.ArrayDeque;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Deque;
import java.util.List;


public class ConsumerProducer1 {

    private static int QUEUE_SIZE = 10;

    private Deque<Integer> queue = new ArrayDeque<Integer>(QUEUE_SIZE);


    public synchronized boolean addWorkItem(Integer i) {
        if (queue.size() < QUEUE_SIZE) {
            queue.addLast(i);
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public synchronized Integer getWork() {
        if (queue.size() > 0) {
            return queue.removeFirst();
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ConsumerProducer1().go();
    }

    public void go() {
        ConsumerThread ct = new ConsumerThread();
        ct.start();
        ConsumerThread ct2 = new ConsumerThread();
        ct2.start();
        ProducerThread pt = new ProducerThread();
        pt.start();
    }

    class ConsumerThread extends Thread {
        public void run() {
            while(true) {
                Integer work = getWork();
                if (work == null) {
                    Thread.yield();
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Thread: " + this.getId() + " received work: " + work);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    class ProducerThread extends Thread {
        private List<Integer> retryList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        public void run() {
            while(true) {
                Integer currWork;
                if (retryList.size() == 0) {
                    currWork = (int) (Math.random() * 100);
                    System.out.println("Thread: " + this.getId() + " generated new work: " + currWork);
                } else {
                    currWork = retryList.remove(0);
                    System.out.println("Thread: " + this.getId() + " retrying old work: " + currWork);
                }
                if (!addWorkItem(currWork)) {
                    System.out.println("Thread: " + this.getId() + " could not add work (because buffer is probably full): " + currWork);
                    retryList.add(currWork);
                    Thread.yield();
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Thread: " + this.getId() + " added work to queue: " + currWork);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Suggest adding `final` to the `QUEUE_SIZE` constant and the collection instance also.

`synchronized` usage for protecting the ArrayDeque collection from concurrent access, but ArrayDeque is not thread safe. Perhaps two threads, one calls `getWork()` and another the `addWorkItem(Integer i)`. Suggest using a thread safe collection instead of ArrayDeque.

Multiple threads may not always have access to `System.out`. Instead can use a concurrent logger or other mechanism to capture output, or have each thread write to a thread safe collection as an instance in `ConsumerProducer1`. Another option is having a `Callable` that returns desired output as a String, with the main routine the only thread accessing `System.out` and echoing that result.

Answer (score 1):

Concurrency is hard enough; don't make it harder by adding threads.

In most cases where you want to divide your work among multiple threads, the right approach to take is to submit `Runnables` to an `ExecutorService`, rather than to manage your own threads.

You also seem to be using `Thread.yield()` as a way of idling until work is available.  The usual mechanism is to `wait()` on the lock until you can make progress.  Using that approach, getWork might look like this:

```
public synchronized Integer getWork() {
    // While our progress is blocked...
    while(queue.isEmpty()) {
        // release the lock; idle until we are woken up
        // and re-acquire the lock
        wait();
        // now we have the lock again, but we still need
        // to check to see if we can make progress
    }

    // Now we have the lock AND a queue that isn't empty

    // Take a moment to notify the other threads that are waiting that
    // the state of the queue has changed, and they may need to re-evaluate
    // whether they can make progress.  To be honest, I'm not sure if you
    // need it when you have one non-blocking producer.
    notifyAll();

    // grab the data we need before releasing the lock.
    return queue.removeFirst();
}
```

The producer logic definitely needs to notify the idle threads when it has added items to the queue, so that they can wake up and pull them off

```
public synchronized boolean addWorkItem(Integer i) {
    if (queue.size() < QUEUE_SIZE) {
        queue.addLast(i);

        // let any idling consumers know that the queue is no
        // longer empty
        notifyAll();

        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

BTW: I love that you implemented the producer this way.  If the producers are outrunning the consumers, fail fast is often a better approach than blocking (for more thoughts on this, search for "backpressure")

```
            if (!addWorkItem(currWork)) {
                System.out.println("Thread: " + this.getId() + " could not add work (because buffer is probably full): " + currWork);
                retryList.add(currWork);
```

That said, if you respond to backpressure by writing the workload to an unbounded list for later replay, what's the point in using a bounded queue?

For clarity, I would probably write this as

```
            if (!addWorkItem(currWork)) {
                onOverloaded(currWork);
```

Note that [Effective Java](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00B8V09HY), Item #69 would tell you to eschew wait() and notify() in favor of the facilities available in java.util.concurrent.  In this case, a [LinkedBlockingQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html) might be preferred to rolling your own.

If you want to learn *a whole lot* about producer/consumer, read up on [LMAX Disruptor](https://lmax-exchange.github.io/disruptor/).